# New laptop - hub over-current condition

Tags: kernel, usb

I bought a new laptop Lenovo B50-70 and I abe installed Linux Mint. In the syslog is long output og messages:

```
   ....
   hub 1-1:1.0: over-current condition on port 3
   hub 2-0:1.0: over-current condition on port 4
   hub 3-0:1.0: over-current condition on port 3
   hub 2-0:1.0: over-current condition on port 3
   hub 1-1:1.0: over-current condition on port 3
   hub 2-0:1.0: over-current condition on port 4
   hub 2-0:1.0: over-current condition on port 3
   hub 3-0:1.0: over-current condition on port 4
   hub 1-1:1.0: over-current condition on port 3
   hub 2-0:1.0: over-current condition on port 4
   hub 3-0:1.0: over-current condition on port 3
   .....
```

I tried to disable Legacy USB, nothing happened. Running on battery power alone, nothing much happened.
USB connector on the laptop works well, laptop seems to be okay.
It should not be a problem, HW? or kernel? or bios? How can I test it, please?

It's a new laptop so I can send for warranty repair, but I do not know what I should write about the problem.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Do these over-current conditions also appear when there are devices attached to those ports?

Comment: I have done test. I have connected USB sticks to all USB ports, and message about over-current was printed very frequently to syslog, few lines per second.
After about 30 seconds, one USB stick was automatic unplugged, next USB stick was automatic unplugged too, but automatic plugged immediately... last one USB stick working correctly all time.
It seems, that HW on my laptop is broken.

Comment: I installed new kernel - version 3.19.2 and in syslos is visible this output:

`...  
kernel: [ 1404.649690] usb usb1-port3: over-current condition  
kernel: [ 1404.649714] usb usb2-port3: over-current condition  
kernel: [ 1404.790034] usb 3-1-port3: over-current condition  
kernel: [ 1404.857915] usb usb1-port4: over-current condition  
kernel: [ 1404.857963] usb usb2-port4: over-current condition  
kernel: [ 1410.903017] usb 3-1-port4: over-current condition  
...`

After connect external drive to any USB port, in syslog is none output.

Comment: If the syslog is clean when all ports are in use, it's maybe a false overcurrent notifications due to too much noise... There are some hints [here](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-usb-devel/msg00592.html). So **maybe** you can just ignore these messages.

Comment: I have installed Windows with all drivers, and Windows always showing popup message with over-current notification, with plugged USB sticks or with free ports.
I am going to return back laptop to store, it is new laptop with broken HW.